# i cant use dual monitor in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors

*about everything*

I'm still a beginner in using Ubuntu, I want to ask why my Ubuntu can't use dual monitors?

I have 2 different OS on 1 computer. The first OS is Windows 11, I can connect 3 monitors simultaneously,

My laptop specifications:
legion 5 pro laptop AMD ryzen 7 5800 H, NVIDIA RTX 3050 TI laptop

so what should I do first after installing Ubuntu OS and want to use it with dual monitors because when I use Windows OS these 3 monitors can be turned on together

I use Ubuntu desktop with version Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I use Ubuntu desktop with version Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings" > "Displays" > "Multiple Display" . Check and modify your display as needed. Check if specific display is disable.